# Simplify loop to get the attributes of a class

Tags: c#, linq

I have this two foreach loops to get all the attributes, linearly, of one my class.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in GetType().GetProperties())
{
  foreach (Attribute attribute in property.GetCustomAttributes(true))
  {
  }
}
```

How I can simplify this two loops to one loop or to linq operation to get the class attributes ?

Answer (score 6):

You can rely on `SelectMany()`

```
var attributes = GetType().GetProperties()
                     .SelectMany(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(true));

foreach (var attribute in attributes)
{
    // Code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Or using query notation:

```
var attributes=from p in yourObject.GetType().GetProperties()
               from a in p.GetCustomAttributes(true)
               select a;
```